# go) how to i make download service?

Tags: file, go, server

i make upload server
but i can't make download server

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func uploadHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    uid := c.Request.FormValue("uid")
    file, header, err := c.Request.FormFile("uploadFile")
    filename := header.Filename
    fmt.Println(filename)
    err = os.Mkdir("./upload/"+uid, 777)
    out, err := os.Create("./upload/" + uid + "/" + filename)
    _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/goupload", uploadHandler)
    r.POST("/godownload", downloadHandler)
    // listen and server on 0.0.0.0:8080
    r.Run()
}
```

so, how to i make download server?

i will use post uid & downloadfilename.

Comment: You need to read about the `Content-Type` HTTP header. Write the correct headers and write your data for downloading into the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an new handler and use [ServeContent](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeContent) or [ServeFile](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) from http package.

```
f, err := os.Open(yourFile)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer f.Close()

fileInfo, err := f.Stat()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

http.ServeContent(w, r, fileInfo.Name(), fileInfo.ModTime(), f)
```

To force the browser open the download dialog, add a `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` headers and write to file content to the body:

```
f, err := os.Open(yourFile)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer f.Close()

w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=YourFile")
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))

io.Copy(w, f)
```